# Set UiView background image like apple default style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new on Cocoa OBJC and iPhone dev.
Where to find the default background that apple uses everywhere (like the one on the iphone's default setting app) ?
It's possible to set the image from interface builder or you have to set by line code?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Carl's answer: if you create a `UITableView` in the grouped style, either via Interface Builder or using the `-initWithFrame:style:` method with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, you'll get that background by default. Before iOS 6, if you wanted to apply it to another view, you could set that view's `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`; since then, that method has been deprecated and you need to create the color yourself.

Comment: do you mean that I can use this background in any uiview and not just uitableview?

Comment: Yes. All UIViews support patterned background colors.

Comment: ok you did mean that!:)
Now I have a UiTableView with example data on interface builder and nothing to simulator, i think is good, but not too much "pro" using a uitableview either than a normal uiview. So where I have to apply your code?

Comment: and for the second question, where to find a good site resource for png and candy for iphone app dev?

Comment: i really don't understand how to change the uiview background with the uitableview's one but I where. Changes if add the uiview from the interfacebuilder and not by initialing it source code?!thanks for help

Comment: `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` has been deprecated since iOS 6. See here for solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

That's just the default background of a `UITableView`.  If you make a `UITableView`, you'll get the background.

Comment: ok, the default one didn't but with grouped selected is ok.
Thanks